# MediaPlayer volume is too low

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using MediaPlayer to play an OGG format audio. The problem is that the emulator is playing at a low volume. The same sound, at the same system volume on the same computer, is about half as loud as the emulator.

For the simulator I set the maximum volume: Alarm, Media, Call,Ring all four modes are maximum.

For the mediaplayer,code below:

```
val audioManager = context.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as android.media.AudioManager
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(
            STREAM_ALARM,
            audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(STREAM_ALARM),
            0
        )
mCurrentPlayer = MediaPlayer()
mCurrentPlayer.setAudioStreamType(STREAM_ALARM)
mCurrentPlayer.setDataSource(afd)
mCurrentPlayer.prepare()
mCurrentPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume)
mCurrentPlayer.start()
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I think you must go for exoplayer  by Google rather than using media player

Comment: I tried ExoPlayer, but when multiple tracks were being played synchronously, the player started to jam, and when I looked at the code of others on Github, I found that they were also jamming. After looking at similar apps, I found that they were using MediaPlayer instead of ExoPlayer, and the volume was also too low compared to the source audio.